# How do I add script dynamically and run it. I am able to add it to my html code, but it is not executed

Tags: javascript, html, ads

I have a blog (40+ articles)
In each article, there is a div element with id="ad".

I want to write a script with will add the (another) script in that div, so ad will be displayed only there where the div is.
My ad provider is `adsterra`.

I want to add the code below in my target element (div tag). This code is provided my ad provider.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    atOptions = {
        'key' : '648ed94d49e39704aa01f7',
        'format' : 'iframe',
        'height' : 90,
        'width' : 728,
        'params' : {}
    };
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://botsane.cm/648ed9424ed890aeb17/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
</script>
```

I have done the following (which doesn't work).

```
document.getElementById('ad').innerHTML = `(the code above with correct escapes)`;
```

I have tried the following code too, which is again not working.

```
    var div = document.getElementById('ad');
    var ad = document.createElement('script');
    ad.text = `
    atOptions = {
        'key' : '648ed94d49e39704aa01f7',
        'format' : 'iframe',
        'height' : 90,
        'width' : 728,
        'params' : {}
    };
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://botsane.cm/648ed9424ed890aeb17/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
    `;
    
    div.appendChild(ad);
```

Comment: It sounds like each of your article div elements have the same id? That is bad practice. Instead give each element an class="ad" and use the document.querySelectorAll('.ad') then loop through each element and add the script tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#accessing_the_matches

Comment: I want to show only one ad per page. Plus you can see how I have added the script but this way it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I wanted to do something such that I don't have to edit all 40+ articles to add code for an ad.

*I could not find a way to insert a script dynamically. Sometimes ad is displayed but out of place (and doesn't look good).*

I removed all the code related to ad, and just left with the code blog application without ads.
Then I changed my view, and decided to edit the theme. My site is powered by Ghost, and I am using edition theme.
I downloaded the current theme, and edited it to show an ad at the end of the article.

Now, if I change the ad provider or what so ever, I will have to update the code at only the one place (in the theme).

BTW, my site is https://blog.nirmites.com

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to leave the `script` tag at the end of the page. However the solution could be the following:

```
const ad = document.getElementById('ad')
const script = document.createElement('script')
script.type = "text/javascript"
script.innerHTML = `
    atOptions = {
    'key' : '648ed94d49e39704aa01f7',
    'format' : 'iframe',
    'height' : 90,
    'width' : 728,
    'params' : {}
};
document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://botsane.cm/648ed9424ed890aeb17/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
`

ad.appendChild(script)
```

Comment: I have used this kind of code, you can see above.
BTW, I have solved the problem the other way. I will be sharing it in a minute or two.

Answer (score 0):

```html
let code = '' ; //js or html code
if(code){
    try {
        let jsCode = code.replaceAll('<script type="text/javascript">','');
        jsCode = jsCode.replaceAll('<script>','');
        jsCode = jsCode.replaceAll('</script>','');
        eval(jsCode);
    } catch (error) {
        let wrapper = document.createElement('div')
        wrapper.innerHTML = code;
        document.body.append(wrapper);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not understand it, can you write the entire code (my code is in the question)? I don't know what <script> refers to, and my script contains a script, so I am confused there.

Comment: code variable is the code you try to add dynamically to the page
I remove the tag <script> if it exists only so I can run the code using eval